# Move part of file to another file

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have file with few lines:

> Lines1
>
> Lines2
>
> Lines3
>
> ....
>
> LinesN

I have following code:

My code

```
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{ 
    var str = GetData(line);
    if(str == "Fatal Error")
    {
    }
}
```

During `GetData` I can throw some exception. In this case, I would like to move remaining lines to another file. How can I do this?
Should I declare positionCount? Or is there more smart way?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Wrap it in a try catch? Thats the way you catch exceptions..

Comment: I handle internet disconnection. I get `WebException e`.
If  i get `e.Responce` i handle different cases, but if `e.Responce == null` I return "Fatal Error". After this i should write unprocessed lines to another file

Comment: Could you add better explanation of "Should I declare positionCount?"

Comment: May be i can declare currentPosition. which will be count the amount processing symbol. So i can write remaining lines via `sr.Read(someString, currentPosition, length)`

Comment: Without knowing what GetData does, i don't think we can help you. It's all so vague. What you trying to accomplish with this code? "Move part of file to another file" ok, but what part? at what conditions?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply continue where the error was detected, ie:

```
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{ 
    var str = GetData(line);
    if(str == "Fatal Error")
    {
        WriteRemainingLines(line, streamReader);
        break;
    }
}
```

The `line` parameter would then include the line that contained the error:

```
public void WriteRemainingLines(string line, streamReader reader)
{
    using (var targetfile = ...)
    {
        do
        {
            targetfile.WriteLine(line);
        }
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you iterate over your lines and once you encounter some "Fatal Error" you start copying subsequent lines into another file:

```
var thereWasAnError = false;
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{ 
    var str = GetData(line);
    if(thereWasAnError)
    {
         // write this line to the other file
    }
    if(str == "Fatal Error")
    {
        thereWasAnError= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want GetData to continue processing lines after encountering the fatal error.

Comment: @phatfingers Maybe. Or maybe not. I do not see anything regarding this in the question.